# Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection

Tags: apache, ssl, jboss7.x, cas

I have problem in my application (HTTP) when I want to sign in via JASIG CAS that runs on HTTPS. After redirect from CAS, I get this error on my jboss application server: 
`Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? Exception`
In apache server I use mod_jk library. Can anybody help me with this problem?

Thank's

Answer (score 3):

The message in the exception is perfectly clear. You are using HTTPS to connect to a port that is speaking plaintext. Check the port number in the URL. Typically the port number in an `https://` URL should be 443 or absent for Apache HTTPD, or possibly 8443 for Tomcat.

Comment: Port in the URL is 443 (https://) and in jboss I use 8443 for HTTPS. Maybe there is a wrong configuration of application server?

Comment: When I sign in to CAS via HTTPS and without access from another app, it works. But when I accessing from another app it doesn't.

Comment: Well if the port numbers are correct the server must be misconfigured on those ports, *nicht war?*